# Flink: Why does a break statement in loop breaking the Flink Job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

There is a richCoFlatmap in which a class is instantiated for every input event.
The class has some class variables and method definitions. The class also has calls to those method definition using in if constructs based on certain conditions. The if blocks calling the method definitions are in a for loop. In some cased If a condition is met I want the loop to exist and not call the other functions. For this when I use break the. Instead of exiting the loop  and going back to the RichCoFlatMap the Flink job is exited and terminated. The code is Flink using Scala

I would like to know if there is something I am missing or Flink is not break statement friendly.
And is there any way to achieve this without failing the job.

Below is the error for reference

```
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: scala.util.control.BreakControl
```

Comment: Could you please add the respective code? You can mask any secrets if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly the issue is that You haven't used the `breakable` when calling the `break`. This is one of the differences between Java and Scala.

Scala handles break differently than Java and it needs a special construct called the `breakable` block.

You can find more info [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-break-continue-examples-breakable/)/